# Comparison test for two datasets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, multiple-comparisons, matching

I have two sets of data A (n=100) and B (n=10000).Given 40 data points of B match with A, I want to run some tests on the matched and unmatched data points to see if they are significantly different. For example, if the average points and reliability score for the matched and unmatched set is significantly different?

I also want to run some additional tests. For example, if the B points detected in peak hours are significantly more likely to be matched compared to off peak hours?

What are some suitable tests for these?

Comment: What does "*40 data points of B match with A*" mean ?

Comment: For me A is ground truth and 40 data points of B are validated by A- thats what I meant by matching

Comment: I could be wrong, but if there are exactly 40 cases in each condition, a simple t-test would be okay if it is just between two groups, though the type of t-test may differ depending on things like whether or not the variance in each group is the same, etc. However, that is factoring in that there aren't a ton of other confounds involved.

Comment: So, is it the case that you want to compare groups, *Matched* and *Unmatched* ?  And *Matched* has 40 observations, and then does *Unmatched* have 60 observations or 9960 observations ?  ...  I don't understand how 10000 observations can either match or not match to 100 observations.